# How to Switch to a particular window using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to switch to a window.

After I click on a link *"Click here to Login"*, multiple windows pop up of which one window is for login page.

I am redirected back to the click here to login page instead of the login window.

Below is the code:

```
String baseUrl = "***THE URL***";
driver.get(baseUrl);
String handle = driver.getWindowHandle();//Return a string of alphanumeric window handle
System.out.println(handle);
driver.findElement(By.id("LinkButton1")).click();
try {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error" + e);
}
for (String handle1 : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    System.out.println(handle1);
    driver.switchTo().window(handle1);
}
driver.manage().window().maximize();  //maximize browser
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.id("txtUserId")).sendKeys("1227388");
driver.findElement(By.name("txtPwd")).sendKeys("Ad@1234");
driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();
```

Comment: Can you, please, explain what is exactly the problem? I don't get it.

Comment: I m not able to switch to window using above code

Comment: Weird, because with that code I can change window. P.S.: I'm using chromedriver

Answer (score 0):

Please try using this:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
```

Comment: hi sir i m using java and this code is for C# is suppose